# Restore window in firefox 39?

Tags: firefox

I killed Firefox and restarted it. 
It opened a new window.

I usually want my 100s of tabs back so I open **File > Recently Closed windows**.

But Firefox 39 has no menu bar. 
How do I access this option and restore that window?

Comment: Is your system Ubuntu 14.04? You should specify this. My Firefox 39 has a menu bar all the time. A screenshot would help. Also, "killed" means crashed or normal quit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hit Alt-F and then go to 'History'.

Answer (score 2):

Or just use the keyboard shortcut to restore a previously closed window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another option (which I always do) is to turn the menu bar back on. Just right click on the background beside the tabs, or just above the URL bar, then select the checkbox by 'Menu Bar'.

Menus are a great way to layout features simply, I have no idea why so many programs are getting rid of them. At least firefox hasn't taken the awful step to one of those atrocious ribbon toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

It might be just a setting, but I use Firefox 39.0 and it has the default menu inside the title bar (or Unity panel), as most windows in Unity do.

Maybe you are in full-screen mode? Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle full-screen/windowed mode.

You can also try if it helps to disable Unity-style menus and use the default menu line. For that, enter `about:config` as URL, confirm the security warning and search for the key `ui.use_unity_menubar`. If you set it to `false`, Firefox uses an extra menu line instead of embedding the menu bar into the title bar or the panel, depending on your Unity setting.